# Custom PropertyDescriptor, not showing value on property sheet

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

My EMF model has a complex attribute that I want to edit using the property view, I followed some examples I found to create a custom CellEditor for the property which works great. However my issue is that I am having difficulties finding the code to set the value which is displayed in the property view for this particular customized property.

I believe the key is the getLabelProvider() method in the Custom property descriptor. I can use this to modify the value which is shown in the property sheet but it only works when I've clicked that particular row. When I first open the property view or if I've clicked another row in the view, I lose the value displayed in the customized property. (It appears empty) I'm struggling to figure out what I am missing.

Thank you! Sample code is below.

**PropertySourceProvider**

```
public class CustomPropertySourceProvider implements IPropertySourceProvider {

private AdapterFactory adapterFactory;

public CustomPropertySourceProvider(AdapterFactory adapterFactory) {
    super();
    this.adapterFactory = adapterFactory;
}

@Override
public IPropertySource getPropertySource(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof IPropertySource) {
        return (IPropertySource) object;
    } else {
        IItemPropertySource itemPropertySource = (IItemPropertySource) (object instanceof EObject
                && ((EObject) object).eClass() == null ? null
                : adapterFactory.adapt(object, IItemPropertySource.class));

        return itemPropertySource != null ? createPropertySource(object,
                itemPropertySource) : null;
    }
}

protected IPropertySource createPropertySource(Object object,
        IItemPropertySource itemPropertySource) {
    return new CustomPropertySource(object, itemPropertySource);
}
}
```

**PropertySource**

```
public class CustomPropertySource extends PropertySource {

public CustomPropertySource (Object object,
        IItemPropertySource itemPropertySource) {
    super(object, itemPropertySource);
}

@Override
protected IPropertyDescriptor createPropertyDescriptor(
        IItemPropertyDescriptor itemPropertyDescriptor) {
    return new CustomPropertyDescriptor(object, itemPropertyDescriptor);
}

}
```

**PropertyDescriptor**

```
public class CustomPropertyDescriptor extends PropertyDescriptor {

public CustomPropertyDescriptor (Object object,
        IItemPropertyDescriptor itemPropertyDescriptor) {
    super(object, itemPropertyDescriptor);
}

@Override
public CellEditor createPropertyEditor(final Composite composite) {
    Object feature = itemPropertyDescriptor.getFeature(object);
    if (feature == MY FEATURE) {
            return new CustomDialogCellEditor(composite, object, this.getLabelProvider()); <-- THIS CUSTOM EDITOR IS WORKING FINE
    }
    return super.createPropertyEditor(composite);
}

public ILabelProvider getLabelProvider() 
{
    Object feature = itemPropertyDescriptor.getFeature(object);
    if (feature == MY FEATURE) {
        return new LabelProvider()
        {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object object)
            {
                return "Hello world"; <-- THIS WORKS BUT ONLY WHEN I CLICK ON THE ROW IN THE PROPERTY VIEW OTHERWISE THE ROW IS EMPTY
            }
            @Override
            public Image getImage(Object object)
            {
                return null;
            }
        };
    } else {
        return super.getLabelProvider();
    }
}
}
```